# Which private key file in private-keys-v1.d directory belongs to which key?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

Since GnuPG 2.1 (https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html), private keys of GnuPG are stored in the `private-keys-v1.d` subdirectory. After experimenting with key creation etc., I found that I have several `*.key` files in this directory:

```
$ ls .gnupg/private-keys-v1.d
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.key
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.key
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.key
...
```

The file names (x+, y+ and z+) looks like fingerprints etc., but are not equal to any of my existing public keys. How can I find which key file in this directory belongs to which key visible with `gpg --list-keys`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `--with-keygrip` option when listing your keys.

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --with-keygrip
gpg --list-keys --with-keygrip
```

You can compare than the output with the content of the `private-keys-v1.d` subdirectory, where the keys are named like `<keygrip>.key`.

Comment: What does it mean if there is no listed key with a keygrip that appears in private-keys-v1.d directory?

Comment: Why doesn't gpg delkey clean this up?